# Easy way to cross reference in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Is there an easy way to add a cross reference, like a keyboard shortcut or a copy and paste method?  I have a document with a lot of equations in it (in the hundreds), and it is becoming a pain to add cross references to the appropriate equation.  So basically I want something like the following: e.g., 'Alt+q' then '5.13' adds a cross reference to equation 5.13.  Is this possible?

I am using MS Word 2013.

Comment: Long term solution from the future me: Use LaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built in solution like this, you can do it with VBA. Below there is an example, it asks for the number and inserts the cross reference, put it in your normal.dotm to be able to reach from any document and assign a shortcut to it and you have your solution.

### Updated code

```
Sub addCrossRefernce()
    Dim n As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim referenceAdded As Boolean

    referenceAdded = True
    v = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems("Equation")
    Do
        n = InputBox("enter number of equation to refer!")

        If n <> "" Then
            i = LBound(v)
            Do Until v(i) = "Equation " & n Or i = UBound(v)
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            If v(i) = "Equation " & n Then
                Selection.InsertCrossReference referencetype:="Equation", ReferenceKind:= _
                    wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, ReferenceItem:=i, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                    IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
            Else
                referenceAdded = False
            End If
        End If
        If Not referenceAdded Then referenceAdded = MsgBox("There is no ""Equation " & n & _
                """ in the document, do you want to enter another number?", vbYesNo) = vbNo
    Loop Until referenceAdded
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi this works to some extent but my equations are listed with chapters such as 1.2, 5.6. But for this I have to put in e.g. 45 if 5.6 is the 45th equation down. Is there anyway that I can enter 5.6 instead of 45?

Comment: Bad news, I thought it'll manage the displayed number, not the index. Possible adaptation of the macro would be to use `find` to locate your caption in the document, select it's number and get its `index` property which hopefully the one you need, but I don't have time to write the code now.

Comment: I've edited the code, now you can enter the equation number as it appears in the document

Comment: Thanks this is much better, without seeming too picky  it gives the references as e.g. '(5.4' is there any way to make it do it like '(5.4)' (where the last bracket is also included within the hyper-link?)

Comment: I wasn't aware you have brackets around the number, just amend  both expressions: `v(i) = "Equation (" & n & ")"`

Answer (score 3):

In Word 2010 at least you can bring up the dialog with Alt-I-N-R (Alt chording is optional for the N and R). Then Alt-W to switch focus to the numbered item list. Then type the number you need. Only goes to the top level of numbering, so like if you have 5.3 it only goes to 5; you have to use the arrow keys for the rest.

I realize this is a year-old question with an accepted answer, and I'm not even sure how well this work for equations (I use it in outline-format documents), but I came across it in a search so and leaving this additional info for anyone else it might help.

Answer (score 2):

I have written another macro which should provide an even more comfortable solution. Instead of typing something, you just move the cursor to the element you want to cross-reference to:

1. Position the cursor to where the crossref should be inserted
2. Press the hotkey => a temporary bookmark is inserted (grey square brackets if you have configured them to be shown)
3. Navigate to the element to which the crossref is to be inserted, e.g. a figure label or a headline. I find it especially comfortable to use the navigation pane / Headlines to quickly navigate to the destination.
4. Press the hotkey again. The cursor jumps back to the original location and inserts the crossreference there.

You may access the code and some more detailed instructions from [GitHub](https://github.com/Traveler4/InsertCrossReferencesComfortably).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my edited version of Máté Juhász's code

```
Sub addCrossRefernce()
Dim n As String
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim referenceAdded As Boolean

referenceAdded = True
v = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems("Equation")
Do
    n = InputBox("enter number of equation to refer!")

    If n <> "" Then
        i = LBound(v)
        Do Until v(i) = "(" & n & ")" Or i = UBound(v)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        If v(i) = "(" & n & ")" Then
            Selection.InsertCrossReference referencetype:="Equation", ReferenceKind:= _
                wdEntireCaption, ReferenceItem:=i, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
        Else
            referenceAdded = False
        End If
    End If
    If Not referenceAdded Then referenceAdded = MsgBox("There is no ""Equation " & n & _
            """ in the document, do you want to enter another number?", vbYesNo) = vbNo
Loop Until referenceAdded
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

[Máté Juhász](https://superuser.com/users/427317/m%C3%A1t%C3%A9-juh%C3%A1sz) code adapted for adding cross-references to **numbered items** (**paragraph numbers**).

Paragraph reference can be added by entering its number in these ways:

- **7.8.9** or **7,8,9** or **789** for paragraph 7.8.9
- **1** for paragraph 1
- **11** for paragraph 1.1
- **11.** for paragraph 11 (if there is 1.1 also)

Macro code:

```
Sub AddNumberedReferenceDialog()
    Dim tit As String
    Dim chId As String
    Dim refItems As Variant
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim refAdded As Boolean
    Dim chName As String

    tit = "Add cross-reference"
    refAdded = False
    refItems = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeNumberedItem)
    chId = ""
    Do
        chId = InputBox("Enter paragraph number in a.b.c form (use . or , as a separator or no separator 'abc'; if you need to search '11' instead '1.1' enter '11.')", _
            tit, chId)

        If chId <> "" Then
            chId = Replace(chId, ",", ".")
            For idx = LBound(refItems) To UBound(refItems)
                chName = Trim(refItems(idx))
                If InStr(1, chId, ".") = 0 Then chName = Replace(chName, ".", "")
                If InStr(1, chName, chId) = 1 Then
                    If MsgBox("Paragraph [" & Trim(refItems(idx)) & "] was found. Do you like to insert cross-reference?", vbYesNo, tit) = vbYes Then
                        Selection.InsertCrossReference referencetype:=wdRefTypeNumberedItem, ReferenceKind:=wdNumberNoContext, ReferenceItem:=idx, _
                            InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
                            refAdded = True
                    Else
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next idx
            If Not refAdded Then refAdded = MsgBox("Paragraph [" & chId & "] was not found in the document. Do you like to enter another paragraph number?", vbYesNo, tit) = vbNo
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop Until refAdded
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient solution is a macro. Add it to your normal.dot and assign a keyboard shortcut to it. Then, you can create references by just entering the number of the item to cross-reference.

The macro below can be easily adapted to either create references to equations, tables, or figures. The version below creates references to figures.

```
Sub ReferenceFigure()
    Dim refLabel As String
    refLabel = "Figure"
    'Debug.Print Join(ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(refLabel), vbNewLine)
    
    Dim refNumber As String, refItemPrefix As String
    refNumber = InputBox("Enter Number of '" & refLabel & "' item to reference")
    If refNumber = "" Then Exit Sub
    refItemPrefix = refLabel & " " & refNumber & ":"
    
    Dim index As Integer, refItems() As String, refItem As String
    refItems = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(refLabel)
    
    For index = 1 To UBound(refItems)
        refItem = refItems(index)
        If Left(refItem, Len(refItemPrefix)) = refItemPrefix Then
            Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=refLabel, ReferenceKind:=wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, _
                ReferenceItem:=index, InsertAsHyperlink:=True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

For other reference targets, just change the value of `refLabel`. Note, that this also needs to be done if you are using Word in a different language. E.g. for the German version of Word, `refLabel = "Figure"` needs to be changed to `refLabel = "Abbildung"`.

Also note that the macro not work with captions in text boxes due to a [limitation of the GetCrossReferenceItems method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62321307/1523648).